# EF Core 2.1 InvalidCastException on DbContext.Query<T>()

Tags: ef-core-2.1

Given:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public MyClass(ApplicationDbContext db)
  {
     var query = db.Query<IdentityUser>();
  }
}
```

Using ASP.NET Core 2.1, I am getting this exception on the `db.Query<IdentityUser>()` call:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet\`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbQuery\`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.'
```

I ran into this with my own entities and reproduced it with minimal code using the canned `ApplicationDbContext`/`IdentityUser`.  Is this a bug in .NET Core 2.1 or am I doing something incorrectly?

This is the source code from [github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.1/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs) for `DbContext.Query<T>()`:

```
public virtual DbQuery<TQuery> Query<TQuery>()
            where TQuery : class
            => (DbQuery<TQuery>)((IDbQueryCache)this)
                .GetOrAddQuery(DbContextDependencies.QuerySource, typeof(TQuery));
```

It appears to be throwing the exception casting `((IDbQueryCache)this).GetOrAddQuery(DbContextDependencies.QuerySource, typeof(TQuery))` to `(DbQuery<TQuery>)`

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13252) on github since this seems to be a bug from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Comment on my github issued had the solution:

> You cannot call `Query<>` method for EntityTypes. You must use `Set<>`
>   method.

It might be helpful for `TQuery` to be more constrained than just `class` if that is possible.